# Method does not return when it is supposed to and then returns with an incorrect output

Tags: c++, arrays, return

In my program, the method findShortestPath should return when i==x and j==y. I've walked through the code and it reaches this point, setting the shortest route to 5 and the route itself to EEENE. However, it continues on and screws with the route before returning an incorrect output of EENESESE.

The Maze im using looks like this:

```
xxxxx
x...B
A...x
xxxxx
```

and my code is below:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
//Maze Size
#define SIZE 5
using namespace std;

bool isSafe(char maze[4][5], int visited[4][5], int x, int y);
bool isValid(int x, int y);
void findShortestPath(char maze[4][5], int visited [4][5], int i, int j, int x, int y, int& min_dist, int dist, string& p_route,string route);


int main()
{
    int startRow;
    int startColumn;
    int endRow;
    int endColumn;
    int columns = 0;
    char maze[4][5];
    ifstream input("quickest_route_2.txt");
    char data = input.get();
    string route;
    string p_route;
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            while (data != '\n' && !input.eof())
            {
                if (data == 'A')
                {
                    startRow = row;
                    startColumn = columns;
                }
                if (data == 'B')
                {
                    endRow = row;
                    endColumn = columns;
                }
                maze[row][columns] = data;
                columns++;
                data = input.get();
            }
            columns = 0;

            data = input.get();
        }
    }
    input.close();
    cout << "The Maze being solved is: " << endl;
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            cout << maze[y][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    input.close();
    // construct a mazerix to keep track of visited cells
    int visited[4][5];

    // initially all cells are unvisited
    memset(visited, 0, sizeof visited);

    int min_dist = INT_MAX;
    findShortestPath(maze, visited, startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn, min_dist, 0,p_route,route);

    if (min_dist != INT_MAX)
    {
        cout << "The shortest path from source to destination has length " << min_dist << endl;
        cout << "The route through the maze is: " << p_route << endl;
     
    }
    else
        cout << "Destination can't be reached from given source";

  

}

bool isSafe(char maze[4][5], int visited[4][5], int x, int y)
{
    if (maze[x][y] == 'x' || visited[x][y] || maze[x][y] == NULL)
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool isValid(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 4 && y < 5 && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

void findShortestPath(char maze[4][5], int visited[4][5], int i, int j, int x, int y, int& min_dist, int dist,string&p_route,string route)  //I&J Start Point, X&Y End point
{
    // if destination is found, update min_dist
    if (i == x && j == y)
    {
        p_route = route;
        min_dist = min(dist, min_dist);
        return;
    }

    // set (i, j) cell as visited
    visited[i][j] = 1;

    // go to bottom cell
    if (isValid(i + 1, j) && isSafe(maze, visited, i + 1, j))
        findShortestPath(maze, visited, i + 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route,route.append("S"));

    // go to right cell
    if (isValid(i, j + 1) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j + 1))
        findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j + 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("E"));

    // go to top cell
    if (isValid(i - 1, j) && isSafe(maze, visited, i - 1, j))
        findShortestPath(maze, visited, i - 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("N"));

    // go to left cell
    if (isValid(i, j - 1) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j - 1))
        findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j - 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route,route.append("W"));

    // Backtrack - Remove (i, j) from visited mazerix
    visited[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep an eye out for [`while (!input.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). It wants ruin your day.

Comment: *"the method `findShortestPath` should return when `i==x` and `j==y`"* Why should it? There's no `return` statement, whether executed when this condition becomes true or otherwise. You set a boolean variable named `complete`, but you don't check that variable anywhere. Do you ascribe some magical properties to a variable with that name, e.g. believe that assigning to it should cause the function to return? It doesn't have any such properties - it's a variable like any other.

Comment: Apoligies, I made this at 4am and accidentally uploaded an out of data file. I've updated the file and also included the incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, creating and adding a bool solved my issues. I also moved some of my output code from the Main() into findShortestPath

```
void findShortestPath(char maze[4][5], int visited[4][5], int i, int j, int x, int y, int& min_dist, int dist,string&p_route,string route)  //I&J Start Point, X&Y End point
{
    bool solved = false;
    // if destination is found, update min_dist
    while (!solved)
    {


        if (i == x && j == y)
        {
            p_route = route;
            min_dist = min(dist, min_dist);
                if (min_dist != INT_MAX)
                {
                 cout << "The shortest path from source to destination has length " << min_dist << endl;
                 cout << "The route through the maze is: " << p_route << endl;

                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Destination can't be reached from given source";
                }
            solved = true;
            return;
        }

        // set (i, j) cell as visited
        visited[i][j] = 1;

        // go to bottom cell
        if (isValid(i + 1, j) && isSafe(maze, visited, i + 1, j))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i + 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("S"));

        // go to right cell
        if (isValid(i, j + 1) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j + 1))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j + 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("E"));

        // go to top cell
        if (isValid(i - 1, j) && isSafe(maze, visited, i - 1, j))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i - 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("N"));

        // go to left cell
        if (isValid(i, j - 1) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j - 1))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j - 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("W"));

        // Backtrack - Remove (i, j) from visited mazerix
        visited[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
The Maze being solved is:
xxxxx
x...B
A...x
xxxxx
The shortest path from source to destination has length 5
The route through the maze is: EEENE
```